# Ionic 3 send push notification with firebase data vs notification payload

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3, phonegap-pushplugin, ionic-native

Im trying to make firebase push notification work on IONIC 3 using [phonegap-plugin-push with @ionic-native/push plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/)

This is my Ionic info

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.2
Node              : v8.1.3
OS                : macOS Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b 
ios-deploy        : 1.9.1 
ios-sim           : 6.0.0 
npm               : 5.1.0
```

I cannot understand how create create the notification object server-site to make notification work either iOS and Android.
I read all aboout difference from **notification and data payload**, then I cannot understand how the object  has to be to work on all platforms and in all app state (background and foreground).

This is my initial object

```
  $p = array(
        'id'             => $post['id'],
        'title'             => $post['title'],
        'description'       => $post['description'],
        'text'              => $post['text'],
        'image_url'         => $post['image_url']
    );
    $msg = array(
        'title'     => "test",
        'body'      => $post['title'],
        'post'      => $p,
        'vibrate'   => 1,
        'sound'     => "default"
    );

    $fields = array();
    $fields['to']           =  "/topics/news";
    $fields['data']         = $msg;
    $fields["notification"] =  array('title' => 'test', 'body' => $post['title'],  'sound' => 1);
```

So I tried to put together **data and notification payload**
The result is

- Android Foreground ->notification arrived and I can go to detail page
- Android Background -> notification arrived but on('notification') is not called, thus I cannot navigate through detail page
- iOS Foreground -> notification arrived and I can go to detail page
- iOS Background -> notification arrived and I can go to detail page

The only issue is cannot control Android in background.

If I use just **data payload** on Android all works (can go to detail page either in background and foreground) but on iOS notification don't arrive at all.

If I use just **notification payload** notification arrives on Andorid and  iOS but without data payload, so My app doesn't go to detail page.

My question is:
What kind of object I should send to make iOS and Android work in foreground and background??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read all documentation about firebase and phonegap-plugin-push. 
[Here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#background-notifications-2) I found all explanation about notification and data payload.
It's very weird what I read so I decide to open a [new issue](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1890) there.
But I had to find a way out to solve my problem so I used firebase topic condition. I'll explain my way and I hope It could help someone. I dont like the way I used (in fact I hope that plugin'll be fixed), but it works.

1. I import Platform on .ts file where App is subscribed at the topic **news**.
2. I subscribed app to a topic **'ios'** if platform is iOS or **'android'** if platform is Android.
3. When a I send the push notification from server I create a payload like this:

   private function really_send($post, $device_type)// $device_type == 0 iOS  -  $device_type == 1 Android
   {

   ```
   $p = array(
       'id' => $post['id'],
       'title' => $post['title'],
       'description' => $post['description'],
       'text' => $post['text'],
       'image_url' => $post['image_url'],
       'date' => $post['date']
   );
   $msg = array(
       'title' => "Title",
       'body' => $post['title'],
       'post' => $p,
       'vibrate' => 1,
       'sound' => 1
   );

   $fields = array();
   $fields["priority"] = "high";
   if ($device_type == 0) {
       $fields['condition'] = "'ios' in topics && 'news' in topics";
       $fields["notification"] = array(
           'title' => 'Title',
           'body' => $post['title'],
           'sound' => 'default',
           'icon' => 'notification_icon'

       );
   } else {
       $fields['condition'] = "'android' in topics && 'news' in topics";
   }
   $fields['data'] = $msg;


   $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

   $headers = array
   (
       'Authorization: key=xxxx',
       'Content-Type: application/json'
   );

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   ```

   }

This function is called twice (once for iOs with deviceType = 0 and once for Android with deviceType = 1) and I use [topic condition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)
 So I create two different payload.
In this way I made it work both iOS and Android in background and foreground status